# How can i burn .cab file (a single .Cab file has 6.25 gb size) on dvd

Tags: dvd, burning

I m unable to burn .cab file (a single .Cab file has "6.25 gb" size) on dvd . I have read n tried many options given in web but it didn't work for me.

First: I split "Cab files" by many software like  winrar , poweriso , winzip. when i burn, it burned all files on dvd, now i copied all the files from dvd to pc it copied, but when i select 'first file' n click "extract here" , it extract file some minutes after that it shows error("Cant read the file from Source disk").

Second: I burn .Cab file(single file "6.25 gb" size), on DVD 9 (8.5 gb) by     imgburn , poweriso , alcohol and nero all of it shows error. Unable to burn. My lg writer has feature to burn dual layer dvds, i burn many dual layer dvds but not succeeded in the case of .Cab files.

Plz tell me Solution , n thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You archived and/or split the file, burnt the parts to multiple DVDs, then copied all parts back to your PC and they failed to extract?

   Try burning again at slow speeds on good quality media, and when you copy all the parts back to a single folder on your PC make sure you don't rename any of them. If you used an archiver like WinRAR check that the parts are undamaged with the help of its *Test archived files* feature. If they still fail to extract then it's probably a hardware issue with your DVD burner.
2. You were unable to burn the file as-is to a dual-layer DVD?

   There's nothing special about CAB files or burning them to disc, so again seems like either bad hardware or user error perhaps. The latter can involve attempting to burn a larger than 4GB file to disc while using the [ISO 9660](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660#The_2.2F4_GiB_file_size_limit) file system. As Wikipedia states, "It is, however, possible to circumvent this limitation by using the multi-extent (fragmentation) feature of ISO 9660 Level 3 to create ISO 9660 file systems and single files up to 8 TB". I would highly recommend however that you do *not* use this hack and instead use [UDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format) instead:

   [image: 1]